# Is there a standard way to attribute/cite python code?

Tags: python, comments, citations

I'm using someone else's code verbatim and I would like add commented link to attribute the code to them.

Right now I have:

```
#this code was taken from this page:
#https://www.<the website>.com
```

Is there a stylistic standard or common practice for code attribution in python?

Answer (score 1):

If you took someone else's code verbatim, then that code is subject to copyright protection. If you have a license to use the code, follow the instructions in the license. If you do not have a license to use the code, stop using it.

The standard practice for code attribution is to put in the code precisely what the copyright owner requires.

EDIT: The license in use appears to be a Creative Commons license. If so, follow the Creative Commons attribution requirements and recommendations: https://wiki.creativecommons.org/Best_practices_for_attribution

Comment: The code is under creative commons, and doesn't request attribution in any way. There is no "I made this" comment already in the code but I still want to reference the webpage. So I'm to understand there is not standard way to do this?

Comment: how to attribute to code that copied from SO answers?